# Preserve leading whitespace within a <td> of a table using Angular

Tags: html, angular, pipe

I'm using a project with Angular and Metronic (https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic/demo1/index.html) and I need to put some information in a table, this information is words that start with white spaces and I need that these white spaces are printed, but the table gives a trim in the words.

This is my code:

```
    <table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm" [mfData]="list" #mf="mfDataTable">
   <thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary text-light">
     <th style="width: 10%"><mfDefaultSorter by="code">Code<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></mfDefaultSorter></th>
     <th style="width: 30%"><mfDefaultSorter by="desc">Desc<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></mfDefaultSorter></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data | filterBy:['code', 'desc']:filterText; let i = index">
     <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.desc }}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

And the result was more or less this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYX0U.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping your values in `<pre>` tags will preserve the leading and trailing whitespace.

```html
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data | filterBy:['code', 'desc']:filterText; let i = index">
     <td><pre>{{ item.code }}</pre></td>
     <td><pre>{{ item.desc }}</pre></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Keep in mind that this will prevent these values from wrapping. If you want to allow the text to wrap and also preserve your whitespaces, you can create a css selector and add `whitespace: pre-wrap;` to it.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answered.It worked very well.

Comment: @MateusKern happy I could help! Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You can change the white-space CSS value

```
td {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```